# What is the differnce between keep alive and http pipeling

Tags: nginx, http

What is the difference or relation between keep alive and pipelining ?
Are they both same or different. Is there any way to enable keep alive but disable pipeling as I'm using only POST method and wikipedia says not to use pipeling over idempotent method such as POST.

Comment: Did my answer http://serverfault.com/a/707681/101203 solve your question?  If so, I'd appreciate if you mark it as accepted so I get credit and also so people in the future who read this know that it was the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep alive keeps the connection open and allows another request to be sent after the current request is finished.  Pipelining allows multiple requests to be sent all at once without waiting for one to finish.  I have a feeling whatever client you're using will be smart enough to not use pipelining over POST and you don't have to worry about disabling it for POST, though I can't say for certain.